# Browse unanswered within a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It does not appear possible to AND two filters, like "Windows" and "Unanswered".  Perhaps an advanced search||settings page I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible. Click on [Unanswered](https://superuser.com/unanswered) and explore the tag on the right hand side

[image]

---

Else suffix a valid tag to https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged/

[image]

Comment: I meant some completely obscure method, not something so obvious that it makes me look blind!  =) TYVM